# Reading a text file data and displaying it into LCD (ARM Language)

Tags: file, arm, lcd

I need to read integer data from a text file representing current values and measure them interactively they should be shown in the LCD display and if a current value is greater than a threshold value the the left LED should be fired. At the end the RMS value and the mean value should be presented on the LCD display. Since this is simulation only, I'm using ARMSim# (version 1.9.1) to achieve that, unfortunetly my skills in ARM programming are limited. I gathered some info which led me to this until now (it is not working and I need a lot of advice to be really able to simulate this)

```
    .global _start
.text
_start:

@----- manipulate file for string reading and lcd writing-----
@----- input mode aperture for the file-----

loopbottonblack: @fire left or right led
swi 0x202 @ checks if one of the black buttons were pressed
cmp r0,#0x02 @left button pressed
beq ActOnLeftBlack @go label "ActOnLeftBlack"
cmp r0,#0x01 @right button pressed
beq ActOnRightBlack @go label "ActOnRightBlack"
bal loopbottonblack

ldr     r0,=nomedoarquivo       @ sets output file name
mov     r1,#0               @ output mode
swi     0x66                @ open file for input
mov     r6,r0
bcs     erroarquivo             @ mistake conditon

@inicio de ler strings
loop:                   @interative loop beginning
mov     r0,r6
ldr     r1,=manipulararquivo        @ loads input file to manipulate

@ler string
ldr     r1,=mystring
mov     r3,r1
mov     r2,#256
swi     0x6a                @read a string in the file
bcs     fim
@ldr    r2,=emptystring         @writes an empty string
@mov    r0,#8               @ column number
@mov    r1,#8               @ line number
@swi    0x204               @writes an empty string to LCD
@linha0
mov     r2,r3
ldr     r2,=mystring
mov     r0,#0               @ column number
mov     r1,#0               @ line number
swi     0x204               @writes a read string to the file
@linha1
mov     r2,r3
ldr     r2,=mystring
mov     r0,#0               @ column number
mov     r1,#1               @ line number
swi     0x204               @writes a read string to the file
@linha2
mov     r2,r3
ldr     r2,=mystring
mov     r0,#0               @ column number
mov     r1,#2               @ line number
swi     0x204               @writes a lcd string to the file
@linha3
ldr     r4,=0
ldr     r5,=300000

loopbottonblack2: @fire left of right led
swi 0x202 @ checks if one of the black buttons were pressed
cmp r0,#0x02 @left button pressed
beq ActOnLeftBlack @go label "ActOnLeftBlack"
cmp r0,#0x01 @right button pressed
beq ActOnRightBlack @go label "ActOnRightBlack"
bal looptime

ActOnLeftBlack: @fires left LED
mov r0,#0x02
swi 0x201 @shows left led (on)
bal looptime @go label "loopbottonblack" and do not end the program

ActOnRightBlack: @fires the right led
mov r0,#0x01
swi 0x201 @shows the right led (on)
bal looptime @go label "fimdoprograma" and ends the program


looptime:               @introduces a delay to see all read lines of the file
add     r4,r4,#1
cmp     r4,r5               @compares r4 and r5
ble     looptime            @if r4 has a smaller value than 100000 goes back to looptime
bal     loop                @end of interactive loop

@end of reading strings
erroarquivo:
mov     r0, #1
ldr     r1, =menserroarquivo
swi     0x69
bal     fim @ goes to the end of the program

fim:
@ == closes the file ============
ldr     r0, =manipulararquivo       @ takes the adress of manipulated file
ldr     r0, [r0]            @ take values in the adress
swi     0x68
swi     0x11                @stops executing

.data
.align
mystring: .asciz ""             @set a variable with a string
nomedoarquivo: .asciz "file.txt"
menserroarquivo: .asciz "nao habil para abrir o arquivo de saida\n"
manipulararquivo: .word 0
emptystring: .asciz " "         @set variable with an empty string
@----- manipulating files to write string end-----
.end
```

Comment: Going to need more information than this, I'm afraid!  In what way is it not working?  What output do you get, and how does it differ from what you expect?  Try to narrow down your question as much as possible.  See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @cooperised I appreciate your advise. My main problem now is, i need to read an specific line of the reading file. I do not know how to do that in ARM

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a new question with a reduced scope?  Comments are not intended for extended discussion or Q&A.